# Pebble/Twig Templates: Rendering twice(i.e. nested templates)?

Tags: java, php, templates, twig, pebble

Is there a way to render a template twice? For example:

```
{{ myTemplate }}
```

where in my templating context, `myTemplate => "{{ 2 + 2 }}"` so the final output will become 4? In another words:

```
"{{ myTemplate }}" => "{{ 2 + 2 }}" => "4"
```

Is something like this possible with Pebble(or Twig since they are similar)?

Comment: @DarkBee Looks like `template_from_string` has no support in Pebble

Comment: I skimmed way too fast over that documentation. Yes it definitely says no support, so that question i've linked won't be any help to you ([source](https://pebbletemplates.io/twig-compatibility/))